# Bootstrap/JS Collapse laggy and no animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table with rows that can be collapsed, when I click the button to toggle collapse I see the font awesome icon update immediately but the collapse doesnt happen for almost half a second. When the collapse does happen it just jumps instantly to its final position rather than using an animation. Its almost as if it is running an animation that inst being displayed. Even when changing the .collapsing selector to have no transition this delay exists.

Here is the HTML

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.funcName)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="hiddenField funcID">
                @Model.ElementAt(i).funcID
            </td>
            <td class="funcName col-md-1">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ElementAt(i).funcName)
            </td>
            <td class="row-actions col-md-1">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default editFuncButton">Edit</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default deleteFuncButton">Delete</button>
                </div>
                <i class="btn btn-toolbar fa fa-chevron-right expandFuncButton" data-target="#extraInfo_@i"></i>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="extraInfo_@i" class="collapse out">
            <td colspan="5">
                <div class="argsList">
                    @Html.Action("Index", "Args", new { funcID = Model.ElementAt(i).funcID })
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Here is the JS that happens on toggle (I moved the collapse from the HTML to the JS while testing, but it occurs with both methods of triggering)

```
$(function ()
{
    $(document).on("click", '.expandFuncButton', function ()
    {
        if ($(this).hasClass('fa-chevron-right'))
        {
            $(this).removeClass('fa-chevron-right');
            $(this).addClass('fa-chevron-down');
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).removeClass('fa-chevron-down');
            $(this).addClass('fa-chevron-right');
        }
        $($(this).attr("data-target")).collapse("toggle");
    });
});
```

Here is the CSS I tried to apply to .collapsing to remove the transition

```
.collapsing
{
    -webkit-transition: none;
    transition: none;
    display: none;
}
```

All of the data and such on the page works, and the collapse almost works except for this minor but annoying issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is in this line:

```
transition: none;
```

The default value must be **[unset](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/CSS/transition)** and in order to change it you need to set important:

```
.collapsing {
   transition: unset !important;
}
```

In any case, I suggest to handle directly the events: [show.bs.collapse & hide.bs.collapse](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/#events). In this way you overcome the transition at all:

```
$('[id^=extraInfo_]').on('show.bs.collapse hide.bs.collapse', function(e) {
    $(this).toggle();
})
```

```js
$('[id^=extraInfo_]').on('show.bs.collapse hide.bs.collapse', function(e) {
      $(this).toggle();
})

$(document).on("click", '.expandFuncButton', function ()
{
    $(this).toggleClass('fa-chevron-right fa-chevron-down')
    $($(this).attr("data-target")).collapse("toggle");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.js"></script>


<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            funcName)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="hiddenField funcID">
            funcID
        </td>
        <td class="funcName col-md-1">
            funcName)
        </td>
        <td class="row-actions col-md-1">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default editFuncButton">Edit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default deleteFuncButton">Delete</button>
            </div>
            <i class="btn btn-toolbar fa fa-chevron-right expandFuncButton" data-target="#extraInfo_1"></i>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="extraInfo_1" class="collapse out">
        <td colspan="5">
            <div class="argsList">
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="hiddenField funcID">
            funcID
        </td>
        <td class="funcName col-md-1">
            funcName)
        </td>
        <td class="row-actions col-md-1">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default editFuncButton">Edit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default deleteFuncButton">Delete</button>
            </div>
            <i class="btn btn-toolbar fa fa-chevron-right expandFuncButton" data-target="#extraInfo_2"></i>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="extraInfo_2" class="collapse out">
        <td colspan="5">
            <div class="argsList">
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
                1<br/>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Directly handling the events worked for me, the collapse is now much quicker.